# Use retrofit @Expose only in some requests

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

I am using Retrofit in my project and I build it like this:

```
httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    httpClient.connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(logging);

    builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create()))
            .client(httpClient.build());

    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
```

And I have model like this:

```
@Expose(serialize = false)
private int id;

@Expose
private int gender;

@Expose
private long start;

@Expose
private long end;

.... other data

@Expose(serialize = false)
private int teacherServiceId;
```

I know how @Expose works.

There is the problem, that I need to serialize teacherServiceId in one request. In other ones I don't need it.

How to do this without creating new model class and Retrofit instance?

Comment: change from int to Integer ... gson should not serialize nulls by default

Comment: @Selvin interesting idea, will try. Thanks

Comment: check teacherServiceId key is match to server key.